# Unique associative index from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this, i need to get the unique associative index

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 200
            [name] => james
            [place] => ca
         )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 201
            [name] => jana
            [place] => uk
         )

     [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 203
            [name] => jana
            [place] => ca
         )
)
```

That means i need to get the unique 'place' from that array like

ca,uk

Answer (score 4):

Make use of [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
array_unique(array_column($array, 'place'))
```

> - array_column — Return the values from a single column in the input
>     array (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)
> - array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array (PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5, PHP 7)

Comment: @Muhammadali:  [you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)